# How to get location in Android 12 and above when app is closed?

Tags: android, service, location, android-workmanager

I am trying to get location in android 12 when app is closed using WorkManager. But the issue is, it work for few minutes and get killed by the OS. I am unable to find out why this is happening.

What could be the solution for this?

**Question updated with code**

WorkManager

```
class LocationWorker(
    private val context: Context,
    private val workerParameters: WorkerParameters
) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParameters) {

    private val NOTIFICATION_ID = 10

    private var mRandomNumber = 0
    private var mIsRandomGeneratorOn = false

    private val MIN = 0
    private val MAX = 100

    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
        setForeground(createForeGroundInfo())
        getLocation()
        return Result.success()
    }

    private fun createForeGroundInfo(): ForegroundInfo {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            createChannel()
        }

        val notification =
            NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, NOTIFICATION_ID.toString())
                .setContentTitle("Location Sharing")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_location)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build()

        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            ForegroundInfo(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification, FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION)
        } else {
            ForegroundInfo(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun createChannel() {
        val channelName = "location_sharing"
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            NOTIFICATION_ID.toString(),
            channelName,
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )
        val manager =
            (context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager)
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    private fun getLocation() {
        val locationRequest: LocationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
            interval = 3000
            fastestInterval = 1500
            priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
            maxWaitTime = 2000
        }

        val locationCallback: LocationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                val locationList = locationResult.locations
                if (locationList.isNotEmpty()) {
                    val location = locationList.last()
                    Log.d("ServiceDemo", location.latitude.toString()+ " " + System.currentTimeMillis())
                }
            }
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Permission required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            return
        }else{
            fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper())
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity

onCreate method

```
val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
       .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
       .build()

workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)

workRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<LocationWorker>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
       .setConstraints(constraints)
       .build()
workManager!!.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("Testing WorkManager", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, workRequest as PeriodicWorkRequest)
```

I wonder how WhatsApp share location because it doesn't ask user to change the battery mode to unrestricted.

Comment: Can you share a code snippet of how you are running the work request/worker? You can also try disabling battery optimization for your app. `App Info -> Battery -> Unrestricted`.

Comment: val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build()

        workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)

        workRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<LocationWorker>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build()
        workManager!!.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("Testing WorkManager", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, workRequest as PeriodicWorkRequest)

Comment: Doing this App Info -> Battery -> Unrestricted make worker long-running, but I don't want user to do this.

Comment: Please edit your question so that the text is easy to read. As for disliking the solution, there isn't much to be done there. You can only specify the the minimum amount of time between runs and the system decides when to actually run it. If you need it to run at exactly 15 min then they will need to disable battery optimization.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Question is updated with code. From the documentation I am trying to make worker long -running and documentation doesn't say about asking user to change battery to unrestricted. What is the missing piece?